# Objective C variable being set to null

Tags: ios, objective-c

so I am having a problem with a variable in my code becoming null after being set to a non null value. The variable is set here:

```
MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     self.places = [response mapItems];
};
```

When I call self.places outsides this code snippet, self.places is null. Any suggestions?

Here's the class (I took out some methods for brevity):

```
#import "AddFenceController.h"
#import "PlaceAnnotation.h"

@interface AddFenceController () <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *locations;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MKLocalSearchRequest *localSearchRequest;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MKLocalSearch *localSearch;
@property CLLocationCoordinate2D coords;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PlaceAnnotation *annotation;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *places;

@end

@implementation AddFenceController {
}

@synthesize latitude;
@synthesize longitude;
@synthesize region;
@synthesize radius;
@synthesize geofence;
@synthesize places;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.ibSearchBar setDelegate:self];

    self.latitude = [self.geofence latitude];
    self.longitude = [self.geofence longitude];
    self.radius = [self.geofence radius];
}

- (void)startSearch:(NSString *)searchString
{
    if (self.localSearch.searching)
    {
        [self.localSearch cancel];
    }

    MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];

    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchString;

    MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error != nil)
        {
            NSString *errorStr = [[error userInfo] valueForKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Could not find places"
                                                            message:errorStr
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else
        {
            self.places = [response mapItems];
        }
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    };

    if (self.localSearch != nil)
    {
        self.localSearch = nil;
    }
    self.localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [self.localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    self.region = [self setUpGeofence:self.geofence.latitude.doubleValue:self.geofence.longitude.doubleValue];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self startSearch:self.ibSearchBar.text];

    MKMapItem *mapItem = [self.places objectAtIndex:0];
    self.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:mapItem.placemark.coordinate.latitude];
    self.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:mapItem.placemark.coordinate.longitude];
    [self.ibMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone];


....

}

....

@end
```

Comment: `self.places` is set asynchronously in the completion handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the flow of your program: when you call

```
[self startSearch:self.ibSearchBar.text];
```

you kick off the search, and return right away. It is too early to access `self.places` in the very next statement, i.e. here

```
MKMapItem *mapItem = [self.places objectAtIndex:0];
```

because the search did not have an opportunity to return!

A proper way to handle this would be to add another method to your class that handles search completion, and call it after setting `self.places`:

```
// Make this change in your asynchronous handler:
if (error != nil) {
    ....
    [alert show];
} else {
    self.places = [response mapItems];
    // Add this line
    [self searchBarSearchCompleted];
}
....
// Add this method to your class
- (void)searchBarSearchCompleted {
    MKMapItem *mapItem = [self.places objectAtIndex:0];
    self.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:mapItem.placemark.coordinate.latitude];
    self.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:mapItem.placemark.coordinate.longitude];
    [self.ibMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone];
    ....
}
```

This effectively splits your `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` method into "before" and "after" parts. The "before" part remains the same - it tells the `startSearch:` to initiate the search.

The "after" part gets moved into a separate method. It takes over when the search is complete. If you do not need `places` outside of `searchBarSearchCompleted`, you may eliminate the variable altogether, and pass the array as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend logging `[response mapItems]` and `self.places` right before you call `self.places = [response mapItems];`. That will likely shed some light on the situation:

```
NSLog(@"self.places is: %@", self.places);
NSLog(@"map items is: %@", [response mapItems]);
```